# Get mouse x/y position while not in game engine

Tags: python, interface

Is there a way to register a mousemove event that gets called whenever the mouse moves within the Blender window?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you let a Modal Operator run in the background (its `modal()` needs to `return {'PASSTHROUGH'}` in order to not consume any events). An event object is passed as third parameter to `modal()`, which contains the mouse coordinates in window and region space, as well as information about the event itself.

You can react on mouse movements by checking the `event.type`:

```
if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
    print(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y) # remove 'region_' for window coords!
```

Have a look at the *Operator Modal Draw* template in Blender's *Text Editor*, it illustrates what you can do with the mouse coordinates together with a draw handler and OpenGL (bgl module).